# CakePHP Missing Controller Language Route

Tags: cakephp

I moved a CakePHP app from one server to another, but running on the new server gives this error, keep in mind that the ita is the language route where the URLs look like this 
http://www.c2cistanbul.com/ita/post/263

Missing Controller
Error: ItaController could not be found.
Error: Create the class ItaController below in file: app/controllers/ita_controller.php

```
<?php
class ItaController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Ita';
}
?>
```

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp

Routes

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
$par = Router::parse(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],6));
Router::reload();
Router::connect('/',  array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'home','ita'));
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'utente', 'action' => 'logged'));
$url = array('home');   
if (in_array($par['controller'],$url))
{
    Router::connect($par['controller'].'/*/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => $par['controller']));
}

$lang = array('ita', 'eng', 'deu', 'rus','fra');
if (in_array($par['controller'], $lang)){
    Router::connect('/ita/_(.*)', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'stdpage','ita',$par['action'],));
    Router::connect('/eng/_(.*)', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'stdpage','eng',$par['action']));
    Router::connect('/fra/_(.*)', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'stdpage','fra',$par['action']));
    Router::connect('/rus/_(.*)', array('controller' => 'site', 'action' => 'stdpage','rus',$par['action']));

    Router::connect('/ita/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => 'home','ita'));
    Router::connect('/eng/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => 'home','eng'));
    Router::connect('/fra/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => 'home','fra'));
    Router::connect('/rus/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => 'home','rus'));

    Router::connect('/ita/'.$par['action'].'/*/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => $par['action'],'ita'));
    Router::connect('/eng/'.$par['action'].'/*/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => $par['action'],'eng'));
    Router::connect('/fra/'.$par['action'].'/*/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => $par['action'],'fra'));
    Router::connect('/rus/'.$par['action'].'/*/', array('controller' => 'site','action' => $par['action'],'rus'));
```

Comment: Are your routes and config files all copied over correctly?

Comment: You're either missing a route *or* the old server contained special mod_rewrite rules inside a .htaccess or in the apache virtualHost configuration. If you still have access to those on the old server, please have a look there as well

Answer (score 0):

Got it but thank you all, missed the

```
$par = Router::parse(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],6));
```

sorry about that.